# CSS animation works differently when properties specified separately

Tags: css, css-animations

I have following CSS for animating two separate elements:

```
.loading-icon,
.loading-icon-2{
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateXY(-50%, 50%);
}

.loading-icon {
  display: flex;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.loading-icon-2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: anotherspin;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.loading-icon div,
.loading-icon-2 div {
  margin: auto;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes anotherspin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

The only difference is that for the `loading-icon-2` class all the animation properties have been specified separately instead of using the shorthand style.

But both the elements are behaving differently. Could someone please help understand why this is happening or am I missing something here.
See the code working here at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/imdigvijay/pen/wNmLeV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that you're using `transition-timing-function: linear` instead of `animation-timing-function: linear`. When you use the shorthand, though, it implicitly employs the correct property name, making the animation look continuous with no easing.